# Onepage checkout Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout

I've upgraded a magento site from 1.6 to 1.9 and applied the rwd theme to the site. On the checkout after entering the billing information and clicking on either Ship to same address or ship to a different address the delivery box is blank and there no way moving forward.

I found the error causing this to be `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null` and the lines for checked to be

```
<li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1" title="Deliver to this address" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes">Deliver to this address</label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0" checked="checked" title="Deliver to different address" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no">Deliver to different address</label>
        </li>
```

I've done some google search to try and find any solutions to this but nothing which has helped me in the right direction

I've checked the magento error logs and can't see any signs to help me resolve this error further.

Update:
I've uploaded a clean copy of RWD to make sure it wasn't due to missing elemental from the theme but still getting the same errors.

Comment: Still trying to resolve this problem.  No luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Steve Robbins, https://github.com/sandermangel/beforeYouPostHereDidYouTry-magento1

Disable the plugins starting with Local and Community, then re-enable one of the directories see if the problem returns if not then re-enable the other. Once you know if it's local or community then disable the plugins one by one until the problem resolve this will help to narrow down which plugin (if any) is causing the issue.

I've found the problem lies with a postcode finder plugin which is effecting the checkout progress. Gone to the developer to get this resolved.

Update: Turns out the plugin wasn't correctly working with 1.9 even when the developer labeled it working with 1.9 so had to remove the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it can't find the element with `id="shipping:same_as_billing"`.  Are you sure you copied the theme correctly?  You may need to update the templates in your custom theme.  Try switch to `rwd/default` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I've switched to the rwd theme and still having the same errors